# Can I use named parameters with callproc

Tags: python-2.7, sql-server-2012, pymssql

Is there a way to have callproc issue remote procedure calls with named parameters? Currently I provide a tuple of values, as follows:

```
cur.callproc('SelectCustomer',('Jane', 'Doe'))
```

Which is executed like this:

```
exec SelectCustomer 'Jane', 'Doe'
```

I am looking for a way to have pymssql issue this remote procedure call:

```
exec SelectCustomer @FirstName='Jane', @LastName='Doe'
```

The following does not work:

```
cur.callproc('SelectCustomer',{'FirstName': 'Jane', 'LastName': 'Doe'})
```

It issues the wrong call:

```
exec SelectCustomer 'FirstName', 'LastName'
```

Does the functionality I want exist?

Comment: Have you considered using `.execute()` instead of `.callproc()`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am choosing whether to use execute() or callproc()

Comment: Well I couldn't find any specifics [in the Python docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) about naming parameters, I don't know if it's possible with `.callproc()`. But I do know that with `.execute()` you can name your parameters and pass them in. So, again, have you considered using `.execute()`?

Comment: I am already using execute all over my scripts. But I need to figure out if my original choice is correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586019/named-parameters-with-a-oracle-stored-procedure-in-python