# Named Parameters with a Oracle stored procedure in Python

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

Trying to call an existing stored procedure, but using named parameters, first parameter should retain default value (in this case NULL).

I've spent way too long trying to get this working, any ideas?

```
create or replace procedure so_test(p1 in varchar2 default null, p2 in     varchar2  default null, p3 in varchar2  default null) as
begin
    null;
end;

import cx_Oracle
db = cx_Oracle.connect('/@XTS_DEV.CLIENT')
cur = db.cursor()
cur.callproc("so_test", ('X', 'Y', 'Z'))
cur.callproc("so_test(p2=>:1, p3=>:2)", ('Y', 'Z'))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PatrickJolliffe\so_test.py", line 5, in <module>
    cur.callproc("so_test(p2=>:1, p3=>:2)", ('Y', 'Z'))
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00801: internal error [22503]
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation (http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.callproc) covers this but since no examples are provided there I can see how that might be confusing. :-)

For your example, this is what you want:

```
cursor.callproc("so_test", keywordParameters = dict(p2 = "Y", p3 = "Z"))
```

Comment: How would this return, with a list of input and output in the same order as procedure?